# UIWebview: Why do my images not load?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Using UIWebview with basic authentication ( authentication works ) however I am not getting images downloaded ? can anyone point me in the right direction ?

I am connecting with this :

```
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:sourceUrl
                                             delegate:self 
                                     startImmediately:YES];

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
 NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
[webData appendData:data];
}



 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [_webView loadData:webData 
              MIMEType: @"text/html" 
      textEncodingName: @"UTF-8" 
          baseURL:nil];
```

I get the web page fine but several images do not load.

Comment: What are the image URLs? They may be using relative paths.

Comment: Why won't you use [UIWebView loadRequest:]? Because the basic authentication?

Comment: Yeah I'm not using the loadRequest because of the basic authentication, unless someone knows of a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using relative paths you should set the base URL.

Comment: Hmm, but if the connectionDidFinishLoading setting the baseUrl will help ? I did try it and the web view would not display the page.

Comment: What I think that should happen is that the UIWebView loads the page, finds relative URLs to images, requests the images from the base+relative URL with success, assuming that the NSURLCredential during authentication was created with NSURLCredentialPersistence(ForSession|Permanent). Since it seems that it doesn't work that way you can 1) use absolute URLs, 2) download everything and load the webview from a temp dir or 3) use loadRequest and send the (basic) auth info in the header (googling yields this  http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/basic_authentication_iphone_cocoa_touch).